# Not changing origin when passing data to iframe via message

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Let's say I have 2 pages:
foo.com and bar.com
I have a script running on each of them using Tapermonkey. I want to script on foo.com pass data to the script on bar.com.
Because foo and bar are on different domains I can't pass data directly (GM_setValue, localStorage, webSQL).

But I've found this tutorial:
https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/

The trick is to attach iframe with bar.com to foo.com, send data via postMessage and in iframe receive data and save it to the localstorage. Then the second script on foo.com will be able to read data from localstorage.

Here's the first script:

```
var name = "John";
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = "result";
document.body.appendChild(div);   
var barPage = 'http://bar.com/';
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<iframe src='"+ barPage +"' width='100%' height='100px' id='bariframe' />";

$(document).ready(function() {
    var win = div.children[0].contentWindow;

    var script = "window.addEventListener('message',function(e){if(e.origin!=='http://bar.com/'){console.log('wrong origin: '+e.origin);return}alert(e.data);var payload=JSON.parse(e.data);localStorage.setItem(payload.key,JSON.stringify(payload.data))});";

    var scriptObj = win.document.createElement("script");
    scriptObj.type = "text/javascript";
    scriptObj.id = "barscript";
    scriptObj.innerHTML = script;
    win.document.body.appendChild(scriptObj);        

    var obj = {
        "name": name
    };
    var json = JSON.stringify({key: 'storage', data: obj});
    win.postMessage(json, "*");
    console.log("Sent: " + json);
});
```

What script does:

1) create empty div and add it on the bottom of foo.com

2) after document had loaded I inject javascript into iframe and send data to it via postMessage

3) injected script should receive data and save it to localStorage.

But the problem is I'm still getting foo.com origin inside that script.  And it should be bar.com, shouldn't it?

Because of that when I'd really open foo.com script here won't have this data.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: But I'm not an owner of either of these sites. So what should I do then?

Comment: store the data in a data service or on your server and request it in your user script

Comment: like firebase ?

Comment: sure...good example

Comment: Can I send it to my own php server, save data and then read it?

Comment: yes...same concept and that's what I suggested above

Comment: That's what I though.. but I've created very simple $.ajax and it's not working. As I found out it's due same origin policy...

Comment: need to enable cors or use jsonp if use own server, easily enabled in a service like firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access inside the cross origin iframe you are creating to append anything to it this way due to *"same origin policy"*.

You need an html page from `bar.com` that has the postMessage listener in it to make your approach work